# Python 2.7 Argparse Yes or No input

Tags: python, python-2.7, unix, argparse

I'm trying to use argparse to create an instance in which I type into my Unix console:

```
python getFood.py --food <(echo Bread) --calories yes
```

I have implemented the food option and want to add a calories yes or no option (binary input) using argparse which will determine whether to call the calories method from a class I imported.

My current code main routine is:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Get food details.')
parser.add_argument('--food', help='name of food to lookup', required=True, type=file)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

This successfully allows me to use the first food option shown above which returns food details.

Basically I want to add a second binary option which if the user indicates true, will call an additional method.  Any help for how I would edit my main routine argparse arguments?  I am still very new to argparse.

Comment: what? I understand all the words but I dont understand what you are trying to do

Comment: `type=file` works but probably does not do what you expect.  In Python2 `file` is the same as `open`, the function that opens a file.  So yes, you can do `args.food.read()`.  `type=argparse.FileType('r')` gives more control over how the file is opened.  `file` is not defined in Python3.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could simply add an argument with `action='store_true'`, which will default `args.calories` to False if the `--calories` is not included. To further clarify, if the user adds `--calories`, `args.calories` will be set to `True`.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Get food details.')
# adding the `--food` argument

parser.add_argument('--food', help='name of food to lookup', required=True, type=file)
# adding the `--calories` argument
parser.add_argument('--calories', action='store_true', dest='calories', help='...')
# note: `dest` is where the result of the argument will go.
# as in, if `dest=foo`, then `--calories` would set `args.foo = True`.
# in this case, it's redundant, but it's worth mentioning.

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.calories:
    # if the user specified `--calories`, 
    # call the `calories()` method
    calories()
else:
    do_whatever()
```

If, however, you would like to specifically check for `yes` or `no`, then replace the `store_true` in

```
parser.add_argument('--calories', action='store_true', dest='calories', help='...')
```

with `store`, as shown below

```
parser.add_argument('--calories', action='store', dest='calories', type='str', help='...')
```

This will then allow you to check later for

```
if args.calories == 'yes':
    calories()
else:
    do_whatever()
```

Do note that in this case I added `type=str`, which parses the argument as a string. Since you specified that the choices are either `yes` or `no`, `argparse` actually allows us to further specify the domain of possible inputs with `choices`:

```
parser.add_argument('--calories', action='store', dest='calories', type='str', 
                    choices=['yes', 'no'], help='...')
```

Now, if a user enters anything *not* in `['yes', 'no']`, it will raise an error.

One last possibility is adding a `default`, such that users don't have to necessarily specify certain flags all the time:

```
parser.add_argument('--calories', action='store', dest='calories', type='str', 
                    choices=['yes', 'no'], default='no', help='...')
```

Edit: As @ShadowRanger pointed out in the comments, in this case, `dest='calories'`, `action='store'`, and `type='str'` are the defaults, so you can omit them:

```
parser.add_argument('--calories', choices=['yes', 'no'], default='no', help='...')
```

Comment: I think this is the right answer .... but I cant really tell from the original question ... good job parsing +1  (I dont think you need the dest argument though)

Comment: Note: `action="store"` and `dest='calories'` are already the default. And for `action="store"`, `type='str'` is also the default. So you could omit all of that, and just do: `parser.add_argument('--calories', choices=('yes', 'no'), default='no', help='...')`

Comment: Yes, good point @ShadowRanger. I added the extra parameters to illustrate other possibilities in `add_argument`, but I'll reiterate your points above.